# Can I block all Facebook Messenger conversations?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm only a moderate user of Facebook, and I don't use Facebook Messenger at all. However, if a friend messages me on FB Messenger, I get an alert on my phone that I can't clear without going to the desktop site or installing Messenger. I've found that if a friend messages me, I can block them individually when this happens, but I don't want to have to do this each time. Is there a way to disable or otherwise block all Messenger conversations to my account?

Comment: You should be able to turn off the phone notifications. On Android, go into `Settings` for the app, go to `Notifications`, and turn off the notifications for  "Messages".

Comment: @ale That does not seem to be a complete solution. I still get notifications for unread messages from the _Facebook_ app, even without having Messenger installed.